# Nothings gets recorded when using JMeter for load testing of Vaddin-based app

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, test-strategy

We have been trying to do a `Quick Load test` on one of the [POC application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Concept) developed in [Vaddin](https://vaadin.com) using `JMeter` tool, the server is hosted on `local network`.

The settings for automating `Vaddin application` is picked from this [link](http://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/JMeter%20Testing?p_r_p_185834411_title=JMeter%20Testing). (These are specific steps for `performance testing` of application developed in `Vaddin` using `JMeter`)

After doing the above settings exactly as mentioned in the link above, we are able to record any other web application, but we are facing issues with `Vaddin` application:

```
Nothing gets recorded. Any pointers to this would be helpful.
```

Additional Information:

- The log file has the following information after starting and stopping the `Non-Test Elements` -> `HTTP Proxy Server`, that means nothing is wrong with the setting, but nothing gets recorded for `Vaddin` application either.

> 2011/06/02 17:01:21 INFO - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Daemon: Proxy up
> and running!
> 2011/06/02 17:01:44 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Daemon: Proxy Server stopped

- Manually creating scripts worked for
  us using the tool firebug to get the
  HTTP request.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Does your company have a firewall proxy?

I've run into this same issue with non-Vaddin apps, and resolved the issue by launching Jmeter with proxy info.  From the command line, it looks like this:

```
jmeter.bat -H proxyDomain -P proxyPort -u proxyUsername -a proxyPassword
```